# Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in .htaccess for Https protocol

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, https, http-headers

I have a site with http and https. I set in the .htaccess the following line which runs for http.

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

But with https I get this error.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried the following with no luck.

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=HTTPS

Any way to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for https in .htaccess?

Here is my complete .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Here is my virtual host settings

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain

    ServerName domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/domain.crt"

    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/domain.key"

    SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/domain.ca-bundle.crt"

<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    ErrorLog logs/domain-error_log
    CustomLog logs/domain-access_log common


    <Directory "/var/www/html/domain">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create a .php so that I request the file through request.php?f=main.jpg instead of requesting it directly like domain.com/main.jpg

It's a little ugly work around but it works. Of course I had to add the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin like this. That way I don't need to specify that header in .htaccess file.

```
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'],'safedomain') !== false) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the complete .htaccess I don't exactly know but when more processing is done within Apache adding the condition `always` might be needed:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

The [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header) explains it as follows:

> When your action is a function of an existing header, you may need to specify a condition of **always**, depending on which internal table the original header was set in.
> The table that corresponds to **always** is used for locally generated error responses as well as successful responses. Note also that repeating this directive with both conditions makes sense in some scenarios because **always** is not a superset of **onsuccess** with respect to existing headers:
>
> - You're adding a header to a locally generated non-success (non-2xx) response, such as a redirect, in which case only the table corresponding to always is used in the ultimate response.
> - You're modifying or removing a header generated by a CGI script, in which case the CGI scripts are in the table corresponding to always and not in the default table.
> - You're modifying or removing a header generated by some piece of the server but that header is not being found by the default onsuccess condition.

Comment: Thank you, but it is giving me the same response indicating "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"

Comment: And changing the order of directives ?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure what do you mean. @HBruijn

Comment: I added virtual host settings and complete .htaccess file.

Comment: Add the Header directive to the top of your configuration,  Apache parses directives in order so sometimes the setting one before the other leads to unexpected results.

Comment: I put the <IfModule mod_headers.c> in the top, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a self signed certificate?

http://dev.housetrip.com/2014/04/17/unleash-your-ajax-requests-with-cors/

> You may encounter difficulties when the request is targeting a HTTPS server using self signed certificates. A possible workaround would be add the certificate in your trusted list. The certificate that comes with the thin webserver will fall under this category.